# Passing Arraylist<String> as parameters for JDBCTemplate with "in" statement in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I am receiving an ArrayList of string as parameters and I want to use it as parameters in the jdbc. I tried using it with batchUpdate but in that case I need to create the List<Object[]> and I need to hardcode the parameters definition in the SQL query. I want to pass the parameters as ArrayList and to be used in a single place in the "in" statement of the query (Like dynamically picking all the elements in the parameters>.

```
List<String> x = ex.getInt().getHeader("x", List.class);
String sql = "insert into tuu (userId, userGroupId) " +
                "select userId, ug.userGroupId " +
                "from general2 gt join tu on gt.v_3 = tu.userName " +
                "join tug ug " +
                "on (ug.userGroupId in (?)) " +
                "where n_1 is null";
int[] data = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, x);
```

This code is throwing an error:
*java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;*

It is compulsory to use ArrayList as parameters. I can't convert it into the string like "1,2,4" and just adding it to the sql query string and make use of jdbctemplate without using any parameters.

Comment: JDBC doesn't support this. It needs a `?` for each element in the list. What you can do is used the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` which does support this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ug.userGroupId` is Integer. and you are comparing with `List<String> x` which is String. First, cast the `List<String> x`  to `List<Integer> x`. then run the code. That might work.
thank you.